# How to remove tabs at start and end of varchar field in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I've got a field in a mysql db that's a varchar(255).  I've looked at trim() to remove leading and trailing whitespace, but it seems to only handle spaces, not tab characters:

```
 UPDATE mytable SET textfield = TRIM(textfield);
```

Does anyone know how to also strip tabs off the start and end of a field?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can still use the [`TRIM`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) function, and specify the character to be trimmed:

```
UPDATE mytable SET email = TRIM(CHAR(9) FROM TRIM(email));
```

Comment: `BOTH` is assumed and doesn't need to be specified. +1 since OP's update.

Comment: This solution is not complete, as there might be a mixture of '\x9', '\n' and space chars.
Suppose `email` == 'text \x9 \x9\n'

Comment: Good lord! `CHAR(9)` it is...! I kept doing `CHAR(10)` (which is for `newline`) and almost believed that my mySQL is broken!

Answer (score 11):

Have you tried this?

```
UPDATE mytable SET email = REPLACE(TRIM(email), CHAR(9), '')
```

Comment: Won't that replace all the tabs inside that field?

Comment: I was also thinking about tabs in the middle ... but then again, an email address doesn't typically contain tabs.

Comment: I don't want to replace all tabs, just ones at start and ones at end... not in middle.  Sorry if the field name email made you think that.

Comment: @Ray If that's the case, then MichaelFredrickson's answer would be correct.

Comment: @Kermit Nope, what if you have something like ' \t \t me@example.com \t' :)

Answer (score 4):

The **TRIM** function provides a good solution for your problem. Just use some like this above:

```
UPDATE yourtable SET your_field = TRIM(CHAR(9) FROM TRIM(your_field));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use replace with either \t or CHAR(9):

```
UPDATE mytable SET email = REPLACE(TRIM(email), '\t', '');
```

Comment: I don't want to replace all tabs, just ones at start and ones at end... not in middle.  Sorry if the field name email made you think that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace with Ltrim and Rtrim: example:

Update Table_Product set product_name = ltrim(rtrim(REPLACE(product_name), CHAR(9), '') where id= blablabla;