# Creating INSERT statements from SELECT statement - unwanted TABs (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a set of INSERT statements using the following SELECT statement:

```
SELECT 'insert into NOTE (id, value, business_key, last_timestamp) values (' , id, ',\'' , value, '\',\'', business_key, '\',\'', last_timestamp,  '\');' FROM NOTES;
```

Unfortunately it has used **TAB** characters to delimit the columns (and these appear within my column values for character fields because i prefix and suffix them with a quote) when it outputs the following:

```
insert into NOTE (id, value, business_key, last_timestamp) values ( 47  ,'  hghffhg ',' 17-1-01-S3  ',' 2015-06-26 14:42:49 ');

insert into NOTE (id, value, business_key, last_timestamp) values ( 48  ,'  1234567890  ',' 17-1-0A-S35BR   ',' 2015-06-29 15:31:57 ');
```

How can I remove (TRIM) these?
I've tried using TRIM around this but get syntax errors!

By the way, I have this SELECT statement in a file (notes.sql) that I pass into mysql:
mysql < notes.sql

Note - The unwanted TABs are not in the original data I am extracting, but a result of the TAB delimited output.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove tabs at start and end of varchar field in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13979169/how-to-remove-tabs-at-start-and-end-of-varchar-field-in-mysql)

Comment: No it isn't a duplicate - my values are not columns in the DB with TABS in, they are the generated output - a result of MYSQL tab delimiting the output from a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I decided to amend the output file that was created.

I used sed to substitute the TABs to nothing !

```
sed -i 's/\t//g' <FILENAME>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT 'insert into NOTE (id, value, business_key, last_timestamp) values (' , id, ',\'' , TRIM(value), '\',\'', TRIM(business_key), '\',\'', last_timestamp,  '\');' FROM NOTES;
```

Comment: No, this would TRIM the content of the field - MYSQL is delimiting the component parts of the results returned with TAB and then my embedded apostrophes to form correct SQL INSERT syntax results in 'TAB <DATA FROM COLUMN>TAB'