# MySQL load data in file ignoring tabs

Tags: mysql

I have a 20GB file full of point data. The data has not been exported correctly and there are tab spaces throughout. What I mean is the file is like this

```
POINT(  -38.071489872015        140.99467884981 ),
POINT(  -38.071489872015        140.99525003481 ),
POINT(  -38.071489872015        140.99582121982 ),
POINT(  -38.071100465759        140.99147345891 ),
POINT(  -38.071100465759        140.99204464087 ),
```

Is there a way to ignore the first and last tab space?

My current load data script is

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads/import.txt' 
INTO TABLE tblImport 
LINES TERMINATED BY ',' 
(@pointData) 
SET 
pointData = GeomFromText(@pointData);
```

but I get the error

```
[Err] 3037 - Invalid GIS data provided to function st_geometryfromtext.
```

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13979169/how-to-remove-tabs-at-start-and-end-of-varchar-field-in-mysql

Comment: @Rene That won't help, the import fails so there is no tabular data to act on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sed` is a very efficient tool for manipulating text data. You probably also want to save the cleaned dataset in case the import fails, rather than cleaning it and piping it to `mysql`, which you could also do.

Try it out with

```
sed $'s/\t*//g' point_data.sql | head -n 20 > point_data_no_tabs_short.sql
```

to clean 20 rows make sure you get what you expect.

If it works, clean the whole file in-place:

```
sed -i.bak $'s/\t*//g' point_data.sql
```

or create a cleaned copy:

```
sed $'s/\t*//g' point_data.sql > point_data_no_tabs.sql
```